# Two Email Accounts in Mail.app / Can I disable notifications for one of them?

Tags: macos, mail.app, notifications

Hopefully this is an easy one! :-) I am working in Mail.app these days in Mountain Lion and I have two mail accounts within. I'd like to disable all notifications for one of those accounts. This means no popups or items in Notification Center.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following:

1. Create a smart mailbox.
2. Choose "Message is in Mailbox" as a condition.
3. Select the inbox of the account where you like to get notifications.
4. After creating the smart mailbox, visit Mail's preferences.
5. At the General tab, set "New message notifications" to your newly created smart mailbox.

Comment: Interesting. Would this entail turning off notifications for both accounts within System Preferences and then instituting the Smart Mailbox?

Comment: I understand it this way: In System Preferences > Notifications, you select the kind of notification you want to show up (and in which style). Here you turn on notifications from Mail. In Mail > Preferences, you select which notifications Mail sends out. Here you select the smartbox.